# Template Haskell Function for Record Accessor Inheritance

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I have two datatypes, `A` and `B`, which I have defined as:

```
data A = A { aFoo :: Int, aBar :: String }
data B = B { bFoo :: Int, bBar :: String, bBaz :: Float }
```

I now need to create a heterogeneous list of `A`s and `B`s, so I define a sum type, `C`, as:

```
data C = CA A | CB B
```

I would now like to define the functions

```
cFoo :: C -> Int
cBar :: C -> String
```

This can be achieved with pattern matching...

```
cFoo (CA a) = aFoo a
cFoo (CB b) = bFoo b

cBar (CA a) = aBar a
cBar (CB b) = bBar b
```

...but this becomes tedious with data types of many fields. I was wondering if there is a simple solution using template Haskell, or if it wouldn't be worth the effort. I have intermediate knowledge of Haskell, but am relatively new to Template Haskell. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve with this pattern here; Why not just have `data FooBar = FooBar { foo :: Int, bar :: String }` and `aToFooBar :: A -> FooBar` and `bToFooBar :: B -> FooBar` and `data C = C FooBar`? If it's all the same to you anyway?

Comment: I'd ultimately like to make `cFoo` and `cBar` lenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

data A = 
  A 
    { _aFoo :: Int
    , _aBar :: String 
    }

data B = 
  B 
    { _bFoo :: Int
    , _bBar :: String
    , _bBaz :: Float 
    }

makeLenses ''A
makeLenses ''B

data C 
  = CA A 
  | CB B

makePrisms ''C
```

That will give you seven functions: `aFoo`, `aBar`, `bFoo`, `bBar`, `bBaz`, `_CA` and `_CB`.

I suggest you read this tutorial: [lens over tea #6: Template Haskell](https://artyom.me/lens-over-tea-6).